# How to display a 2-digit year + ISO week in PDF using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, week-number, 2-digit-year

I would like to have a form field in a PDF that autofills with the date formatted as "YYWK", where YY is the 2-digit year and WK is the ISO week. I have seen code here on how to display the ISO week (https://weeknumber.net/how-to/javascript). What I don't know how to do is to integrate this into a PDF document.

This behavior should update the date every time the PDF is printed.

Edit: The 2-digit year is a customer requirement which I have no control over.

Edit2: I was able to get an answer on the Adobe forums, if anyone else ever ends up having a similar question. https://forums.adobe.com/message/9739107#9739107

Comment: (A) Stack Overflow is for asking specific narrowly focused programming question, not asking for primer or opening a discussion. (B) Using a two-digit year violates the standard, so your week-date would not comply with ISO 8601. Two-digit years is nothing but trouble in creating ambiguity, not worth saving two octets of memory and a centimeter of space.

Comment: It seems like this guide might help you: http://www.uwec.edu/help/acrobat9/for-date.htm

Comment: Did you want the date to auto fill every time the PDF file is opened or only when the field is blank? Meaning, once the date field gets populated, should it stick or get updated every time?